# CSS. Break text Inside a bootstrap button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, accordion

So basically I'm using bootsrap, and have an accordion of collapsible buttons. Buttons have 2 columns of text and one icon to the right.

I'm trying to break the text in the second column in multiple lines, so that it fits in the button.

Any ideas?

I have an example in this codepen:

https://codepen.io/averied/pen/gBoxbw

I need to break text inside div id="bloc2"

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
   <div class="col col-lg-4">
      <div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
         <div id="block_container" cols="4">
                        <div  id="bloc1">SmallText</div>
                        <div  id="bloc2">Please break this text it's very large and doesn't fit</div>
                        <button id="delbtn"/></button>
                    </div>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
         labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: <div> should not be inside the <button>

Comment: So how am I supossed to make a button like the image attached?

Comment: which one is button? I assume only the delete icon should be button.

Comment: the whole green background component is a collapsible button. When I click on it, the form with 3 fields shows up.

Comment: O I see, I am going to update the fiddle

Comment: You can use a link with the href attribute instead of the button and <span> instead of the <div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
#bloc2 { white-space: normal; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a special class to the `btn` like...

```
.text-wrap {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

And remove `word-break: break-all;` from the bloc2...

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ePyGRJ

Comment: this changes the height

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to modify your `#block_container` to include `flex-wrap: wrap;`. Try modifying CSS as follows:

```
#block_container
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: space-between;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And

```
#bloc2 {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
white-space: pre-wrap;
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
white-space: -pre-wrap;
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I am not sure though why you want your button to expand in height and not `ellipsis` text.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqpGwe

Comment: This makes the text of bloc2 go under bloc1. I want it to the right. The ellipsis option is not mine to decide (Customer pays the bills!!). Guess I'm left with white-space: normal; Does the job!

Comment: So, just remove ``flex-wrap: wrap;`` from ``#block_container``

Comment: OK.. this does the job, but the "white-space: normal" answer came first, and the result is the same. I'll have to mark that one as currect unless there is an advantage on using this approach. Visually the result is the same. Thanks for the effort